# Dataframe: How to group values in a column to create index for pivot

Tags: python, pandas

> Hi everyone, 
>   I'm super new at this so I'm looking for some help.
>   Please consider the following dataframe:

```
      fruit     sales     price    
0     lemon      ..         .. 
1     orange     ..         ..
2     carrot     ..         .. 
3     potato     ..         .. 
4    pineapple   ..         .. 
5     mango      ..         ..
```

> Lets say that fruit column can be categorized in the following way: 
>   lemon + orange = citrus;
>   carrot + potato = tuber;
>   pineapple + mango = tropical.
>
> After I would like to use this new
>   grouping as an index for a pivot table. , in order to see average
>   price or sales in a "citrus/tuber/tropical" segmentation.
>
> In the dataframe I'm trying to apply this logic on there are too many values to make a ditionary.
>
> Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `dict` for [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) witt aggregate [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
'price': [4, 7, 3, 4, 1, 4], 
'sales': [1, 5, 1, 2, 6, 3], 
'model': ['lemon', 'orange', 'carrot', 'potato', 'pineapple', 'mango']})
print (df)
       model  price  sales
0      lemon      4      1
1     orange      7      5
2     carrot      3      1
3     potato      4      2
4  pineapple      1      6
5      mango      4      3

#dict of mapping
d1 = {'citrus': ['lemon', 'orange'],
      'tuber':['carrot', 'potato'],
       'tropical':['pineapple', 'mango']}
#is necessary swap values with keys and expand them to new dict
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d1.items() for k in oldv}
print (d)
{'pineapple': 'tropical', 'potato': 'tuber', 'mango': 'tropical', 
'lemon': 'citrus', 'orange': 'citrus', 'carrot': 'tuber'}

s = df['model'].map(d)
df1 = df.groupby(s)['sales'].mean().reset_index()
print (df1)
      model  sales
0    citrus    3.0
1  tropical    4.5
2     tuber    1.5
```

Similar solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), but then is necessary change column names:

```
df1 = df.set_index('model').groupby(d)['sales'].mean().reset_index()
df1.columns= ['model','sales']
print (df1)
      model  sales
0    citrus    3.0
1  tropical    4.5
2     tuber    1.5
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, sorry just edited the question as I thought it may be unclear. does your answer still apply?

Comment: Yes, only need change dict.

Comment: Give me a sec, I change answer by your changes.

Comment: if price & sales columns contain too many values to list out, can I ommit them in the dict and just use pivot_table indicating them as values?

Comment: I dont understand. What is desired output? Can you explain more?

Comment: the result in your code is perfect, the only problem is that the values in the "sales" and "price" columns may be too numerous to write in the dictionary. My question was if its ok if I ommit them in the dicitonary and just do something like:
PIVOT1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["model"], values=["price"] )

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but thenlost segmentation. Try it with my sample data.

Comment: Actually on the dataframe im trying to apply your code on the values for the other columns are just way too many to list out..
any other solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately not. :(